# Force user LogOff from application if user is deleted.

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have little problem. In my application users are auth via Azure AD and his user profil is in DocumentDB.

When Administrator delete user profile I need to force log out the deleted user. 
How to do it? Delete action deleting ad and documentdb entry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, you want to sign-out the users after the administrator delete the users profile from documentDB.

If I understood correctly, it is more likely building a real time application that nofify the specific client when the delete action is performed. I am trying to explain it using a figure below:
[image]

And for building the real time application, we can use the SignalR. And you can refer more detail about it from links [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

And another solution for prevent the deleted users to access the proteced resrouces, you can check it before the users access the resources.